# Problem on uniform continuity.

Tags: calculus

Let $f: R \to R$ be a differentiable function and consider the following

$(1)$ $|f(x) - f(y)| ≤ 1,$ for all $x,y \in R$ with $|x-y|≤1$

$(2)$ $|f'(x)| ≤ 1$ for all $x \in R$. Then I need to check which statement implies the other.

Clearly first doesn't imply second.
Since the second statement implies the uniform continuity of function, so it should imply the first statement.

Am I correct$?$

Comment: To see the second implies the first, You can use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

Comment: To show that 1) does not imply 2) you have to produce a counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Mean value theorem $$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(c)\text{ for some }c\in(x,y)$$$$\implies|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)|\cdot|x-y|\leq 1\cdot |x-y|\leq 1.$$ This shows $(2)\implies (1)$.

Counterexample of $(1)\implies (2)$ is $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(4 x)$.